# Alternate proof of Liouville's Theorem (Is it right)?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

First I would like to prove Liouville's theorem for polynomials. To do that, suppose $p(z) = a_0 + \cdots a_nz^n$. Let $p(z)$ be a bounded entire function (with bound $M$). Since $z^n > z^i, (i < n, |z| >1)$, I can relatively ignore other terms so $p(z) = \mathcal{O}(z^i) + a_nz^n$. Now i can choose $z = \sqrt[n]{1/(a_n) \times 2M}$ and exceed the bound, and this would then force $a_n = 0$ and using the same reasoning all $a_i$ are forced to $0$.

Next I plan to approach  a power series $f(z) = a_0 + \cdots + a_nz^n + \cdots$ uniformly by these polyomials and since each polynomial is constant (because they are bounded,since if they are unbounded, their limit will be unbounded), they would converge to a constant function $f$.

I would like to know if my reasoning is correct and if not, I would still like to know if we can prove Livoulle's theorem using similar idea.

Comment: You can't approach a non-polynomial power series uniformly by a sequence of polynomials, though.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say exactly where the error  is because you leave out details. But the proof isn't right (for example you can't approximate an entire function uniformly by polynomials, not that I see how the proof would go if you could).

My point in posting this is to say I really don't think the proof can be fixed. Because if it worked it seems like the same argument would show that $\sin(t)$ is unbounded for *real* $t$:

It's easy to see that a non-constant polynomial must be unbounded *on $\mathbb R$*. Now $\sin(t) = t-t^3/6+\dots$; approximate it by a polynomial. Insert here the parts of the argument you left out. QED.

(I really can't be sure this is relevant bcause as I said I'm not entirely certainly *exactly* how the argument you have in mind is supposed to work. But it does show that a correct version must involve something that doesn't work on the line... And it shows in particular that a bounded function *can* be approximated uniformly on compact sets by unbounded functions.)